# Mystery! Case of laravel auth.login event not being 'heard'

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm working on my first laravel project and I've started making user accounts for initial folks to have a look.

In EventServiceProvider.php, I listen for logins (and the UpdateLoginInfo updates the users' logins count and last login date) like so:

```
protected $listen = [
    'auth.login' => [
        'App\Events\UpdateLoginInfo',
    ],
];
```

It's been working fine from the get-go, but yesterday I had a new user log in (and she even took actions in the app), but mysteriously the login count/date was never updated on the way in!

I've confirmed that it works for me with her account, in chrome, firefox, and IE... Papertrail doesn't have any clues- where else should I be looking for clues, or to try to reproduce it? Is it something browsers/settings can interfere with?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Have you updated to 5.2?

Comment: I'm on 5.1.23- is there a known issue with that version?